# I have France-Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen, paris, prague

Just wanted to check because I have multiple Schengen Visa and during the application I applied France as I will be spending more days in Paris and that is my point of entry. However the ticket I've booked going to Paris is through Czech Airlines and I have 12 hours layover at Prague-Vaclav airport. I want to check if I can go out from the airport and have a quick tour at Prague City Center?

Comment: If your ticket to Paris is through Prague, then Prague will be your point of entry. (But it doesn't really matter what your point of entry is).

Comment: To elaborate on @HenningMakholm's comment: you will clear immigration controls in Prague only (meaning you can leave the airport). The flight from Prague to Paris is an internal Schengen flight, so there will be no systematic immigration control at either end.

Answer (score 0):

duplicate question
[Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

in short, yes you can go and enjoy the  Prague City Center :-)